# Get value of a field attached to a user entity based on currently logged in user

Tags: users

I add a taxonomy selection to the registration from *config/account* called `field_user_class`.

Now for my module I need a function that returns the this field value for the currently logged in user, and shows it to them.

I just need the function to return this field for the logged in user.

Answer (score 1):

```
global $user;
// Only if logged in
if($user->uid) {
  $logged_in_user = user_load($user->uid);
  $field_user_class = field_get_items('user', $logged_in_user, 'field_user_class');
  // Do stuff with array $field_user_class
}
```

Comment: I have a question.I called the filled in the account page "filed_user_class".But when I saw the database that this field is saving as "field_data_field_user_class". Is this making problem?

Comment: I use this code in a function.But it says Fatal error: Call to undefined function user_load().

Comment: You accepted the answer, I guess you sorted out the fatal error?

Comment: I accept the answer because it's the way of solving my problem. But I have the fetal error with this code yet. I am using this code in my own module.

Comment: Regarding `field_data_field_user_class` and field called `field_user_class` this is correct. There should be no problem as that's the correct name for the field table in the database. Regarding `user_load` it's a [valid Drupal 7 function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_load/7). You are getting a "fatal error: undefined function user_load" because you're probably not using this code within the scope of Drupal. See kiamlaluno's answer above/below.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a function that returns the value of a field for a user account, but you can use the following code.

```
$account = user_uid_optional_load();
$items = field_get_items('user', $account, 'field_user_class');
```

If you need to just display the entity field, then you should use the following code.

```
$account = user_uid_optional_load();
$items = field_view_field('user', $account, 'field_user_class');
```

In the latter case, keep in mind the notes shown in the documentation for [field_view_field()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_field/7):

- Do not use inside node (or other entities) templates; use [render($content[FIELD_NAME])](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/render/7) instead
- Do not use to display all fields in an entity; use [field_attach_prepare_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_prepare_view/7) and [field_attach_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_view/7) instead
- The [field_view_value()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_value/7) function can be used to output a single formatted field value, without label or wrapping field markup

Bear in mind that you cannot use the global `$user` variable, since that doesn't contain a full-loaded user object. That is why you need to use a function that loads the user object from the database, which is what [user_uid_optional_load()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_uid_optional_load/7) does.